# How to add plus sign in numbers - Bootstrap TouchSpin Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the code below. How can I add `+` for numbers greater than `0` or remove the `-` sign from the numbers less than `0` on using Bootstrap [TouchSpin library](https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/)?

```js
$("input[name='demo1']").TouchSpin({
  min: -6,
  max: 6,
  step: 0.25,
  decimals: 2,
  boostat: 5,
  maxboostedstep: 10
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<input id="demo1" type="text" value="0" name="demo1">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an event listener for the `input`'s `change` event and add a plus sign (+) to the value of the input  is if it positive as the change event is triggered on the original input by the plugin and can be listened on.

```js
$("input[name='demo1']").TouchSpin({
  min: -6,
  max: 6,
  step: 0.25,
  decimals: 2,
  boostat: 5,
  maxboostedstep: 10
}).change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(parseFloat(val)>0){
    $(this).val("+"+val);//add + for positive numbers
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<input id="demo1" type="text" value="0" name="demo1">
```

Comment: One additional wrinkle is that you can chain the change event handler and remove the overhead of parsing the selector twice: `maxboostedstep: 10}).change(function(){`, etc. Another wrinkle is to specifically remove the sign if the value is zero, in case the user types the value in.